# Conditional logic for crispy form

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I've a form and I wanted to know how I was supposed to hide the field "conditionalWeb" until the user choose "Web application" for the typeOfTheproject field?

I've made my research online but I absolutely don't know how to proceed... Any help would be nice :)

```
from django import forms
from configurator import models
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout
from .models import TypeOfProgram, Language, Framework, Database
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import (PrependedAppendedText, PrependedText, FormActions)
    
class ConfiguratorForm(forms.Form):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.form_show_labels = False

    queryOfProject = TypeOfProgram.objects.values_list('name')
    queryOfFramework = Framework.objects.values_list('name','version')
    queryOfDatabase = Database.objects.values_list('name','version')
    listFramework = []
    listProject = []
    conditionalWeb=[]
    listFramework=[((q[0],q[1]),q[0]+" version "+q[1])for q in queryOfFramework]
    listProject=[(q[0],q[0])for q in queryOfProject]
    listDatabase = [((q[0],q[1]),q[0]+" version "+q[1])for q in queryOfDatabase]

    typeOfTheproject = forms.ChoiceField(choices = listProject)
    conditionalWeb = forms.ChoiceField (choices = [('nothing', '----'),("Only Backend","Only Backend"),("Only Frontend","Only Frontend")])
    wantedFramework = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = listFramework)
    wantedDatabase = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = listDatabase)
    helper.layout = Layout(
        'typeOfTheproject',
        'wantedFramework',
        'wantedDatabase',
        FormActions(Submit('Finalize and find the result','Finalize and find the result', css_class="btn btn-success")) 
    )
#Not Working
    if typeOfTheproject is 'Web application':
        helper.layout.append('conditionalWeb')
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple javascript for the task:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    hideShow()
})

// call hideShow when the user clicks on the project_type dropdownlist
$('#id_typeoftheproject').click(function(){
    hideShow()
});
function hideShow(){
    if(document.getElementById('id_typeoftheproject').value == "7")
    {
        $('#id_conditionalweb').show();
    }
else 
    {
    $('#id_conditionalweb').hide();
    }
}
```

You need to find the actual ids of the fields from database and replace *#id_typeoftheproject* and *#id_conditionalweb* . Also the value '7' needs to be replaced with id of web application.